# find a way to reorganize sql table

Tags: sql

I am working on a table like below:

| class | parameter | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | name | John |
| A | city | NY |
| A | year | 2022 |
| B | name | ANNA |
| B | city | NM |
| B | year | 2021 |

I want to save it in new table like this:

| class | name | city | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | John | NY | 2022 |
| B | ANNA | NM | 2021 |

Comment: Use `Pivot` to do this. Check [Dynamic pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server) and [Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69951986/sql-query-with-pivot)

Comment: Mysql is not SQL server - please correct your tags

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with *Sql Server* using `pivot`.

```
select *
from   t
pivot (max(value) for parameter in([name], [city], [year]))  pvt
```

| class | name | city | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | John | NY | 2022 |
| B | ANNA | NM | 2021 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EgSFSR_Z?hide=12)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with *Postgres* using `crosstab`

```
select *
from crosstab(
  'select class, parameter, value
   from t')
as t(class text, name text, city text, year text);
```

| class | name | city | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | John | NY | 2022 |
| B | ANNA | NM | 2021 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4nuldkLQ?hide=4)

Answer (score 0):

You may use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT class, MAX(CASE parameter WHEN 'name' THEN value END) name,
              MAX(CASE parameter WHEN 'city' THEN value END) city,
              MAX(CASE parameter WHEN 'year' THEN value END) year
FROM table_name
GROUP BY class
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7qkB2gBU), works on both MySQL and SQL Server.